# Backup and restore Osmo-pim

Tags: backup, restore, pim

I have entered names, addresses, birthdays and other information into [Osmo-pim](http://clayo.org/osmo/). It has worked great thus far, but my fear would be losing this information if my computer crashes. I am running Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon 64-bit.

How can I backup and restore the information that I have entered into [Osmo-pim](http://clayo.org/osmo/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

As of Osmo 0.2.14, there is a Backup and Restore button included on the main screen which makes this whole process much simpler.

[image]

After you click backup, you see the below screen.
[image: Osmo 0.2.14 save screenshot]

After you click restore, you see the below screen.
[image: Osmo 0.2.14 restore screenshot]

---

**Backup**

Run the following command

```
cp -R ~/.osmo/ {backupDestination}
```

**Restore**

1. Install a clean copy of [osmo-pim](http://clayo.org/osmo/)
2. Run the following command in the terminal

> cp -R {backupDestination} ~/.osmo/

**Additional Information**

To determine where [Osmo-pim](http://clayo.org/osmo/) stores its files, you just need to review the man page with the following command.

```
man osmo
```

Within the man page, it explains the following.

```
 FILES
       $HOME/.osmo/calendar_notes.xml - calendar groups and notes
       $HOME/.osmo/config.xml - configuration
       $HOME/.osmo/contacts_records.xml - contacts data
       $HOME/.osmo/ical_files.xml - active iCalendar files
       $HOME/.osmo/notes_entries.xml - notes list
       $HOME/.osmo/notes/*.osm - notes data files
       $HOME/.osmo/tasks_entries.xml - tasks data
```

Depending on the amount of information you have entered into Osmo, it may make the most sense to copy the `$HOME/.osmo` folder to your backup location.

There is a [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1874273) on Ubuntu forums that is somewhat outdated and now incorrect.